# Can I unbox an integer with a cast in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, casting

I've hit a case in which I have a class that returns type `object` that I happen to know is merely a boxed `int` value.  The control I am using can bind to an `int` property or a `double` property but it cannot bind to an object that is a ***boxed*** `int` or `double`.  I have to work around this limitation.  I'd like to do so in a very simple manner.

**Edited to add:**  The exception that occurs when I try to do this is `System.NotSupportedException` with the message *DoubleConverter cannot convert from System.Int32*

So is there a way to make a cast to `int` or `double` in XAML that is the equivalent of an unboxing operation?  I already know how to cast a reference type in XAML so I can access some specific, derived-class property.  But I am having trouble with this one because `int` is not a type with properties.

Below is the class (a simplified version).  It represents a ranged set of integers or doubles or even other types for which "min" and "max" values would be meaningful.  So it has to return them all as object.  Regardless, all 3 properties will return the same underlying type in the boxed value, be it `double` or `int` or something else.

```
public class Parameter
{
    virtual object Lower      { get; }     
    virtual object Upper      { get; }   
    virtual object Value      { get; set; } 
}
```

I bind to the control like this

```
<tk:RadNumericUpDown MinWidth="100"
    IsInteger="True"
    Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Minimum="{Binding Lower, Mode=OneWay}"
    Maximum="{Binding Upper, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

Now if I know that the `Lower` property is an `int`, can I bind it with some sort of XAML cast?  I've tried a few things

```
Minimum="{Binding Lower(sys:Int32), Mode=OneWay}"
Minimum="{Binding Lower.(sys:Int32), Mode=OneWay}"
```

I didn't expect any of these to work and they didn't.  But the syntax (if there is one) eludes me.  About the only way I can get this to work is to define a separate property in the class that returns the `Lower` as an `int` value

Is there a way to do an unboxing cast in XAML?

Comment: It feels like you don't need to convert values at all.

Comment: I agree completely.  It seems like I should not.  Frankly it seems ridiculous.  This is a limitation of the control itself that I am trying to work around.  If I declare the `Parameter.Upper` property to return `int` (and make its implementation just cast the stored `object` to `int`) then the control works fine.  But when I leave the return type as `object`, something is trying to invoke a TypeConverter to convert from int32 to double which seems perfectly valid and (I swear) it throws.  But I cannot change the return type to `int` so here I am

Comment: Specifically what I get is a `System.NotSupportedException` with the message *DoubleConverter cannot convert from System.Int32*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run it through an `IValueConverter`:

```
public class NonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) => v;

    public object ConvertBack(object v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) => v;
}
```

Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NonConverter x:Key="nonConverter"></local:NonConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

Binding:

```
Minimum="{Binding Lower, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource nonConverter}}"
```

I'm not sure if there is a simpler way.

---

Here is a minimal implementation using a `ProgressBar`, .NET Framework 4.7.2. I'm not sure what happens with two-way binding.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NonConverter x:Key="nonConverter"></local:NonConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="200"
            Minimum="{Binding Lower}"
            Maximum="{Binding Upper, Converter={StaticResource nonConverter}}"
            Value="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource nonConverter}}"
        />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public object Lower { get; set; }
        public object Upper { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
            
            Lower = 1000.0d; // double
            Upper = "2000"; // string 
            Value = 1500.0m; // decimal
        }
    }

    public class NonConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) => v;

        public object ConvertBack(object v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) => v;
    }
}
```

Each of the three properties are assigned a different type for illustration purposes.

The `NonConverter` isn't converting, casting, or un/boxing anything, it's simply returning the same input `v` that it received. The actual conversion is being handled by the framework.

Because `Lower` is a (boxed) `double`, the converter isn't required here.

Comment: Unfortunately the return type of any `IValueConverter` is `object`.  Which would, of course, box it.  Putting me right back where I was before, would it not?

Comment: @Joe I was under the impression that you just need your binding to work.

Comment: I take it back:  This approach works perfectly.  Thank you.  I did not think it would work at all.    I was about to ask you why, but switching my code back and forth between this and before I think I see it now:   Am I correct in understanding that if I do not supply a converter for my binding and the type being supplied (`object` in this case) does not match the type being bound to (`double?` in this case) then WPF tries to automatically pick a converter for me?

Comment: Because (and I apologize for not putting this in question) previously I was getting an exception of type `System.NotSupportedException` and the message was *DoubleConverter cannot convert from System.Int32*

Comment: @Joe Great, happy to hear that it works.

Comment: Am I right about *why* it works?  Because I'm still wrapping my head around that one

Comment: @Joe I don't know what it is about specifying a fake converter that causes the rest of the binding to act right (the answer is probably somewhere in the reference source). `Int32` to `Double` is an implicit conversion, so that's a weird reason to throw an exception if you ask me!